# Text Join for Cell References to skip 0's

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently using TEXTJOIN to show the text in certain cells

`=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,N24,X24,AH24,AR24,BB24)`

Which is working fine, however for some of these cells it will contain 0 and this is returning as the following:

> Mattress,0,0,0,0

Is there a way to ignore the 0's?

So it would return:

> Mattress

I can see how to do this with a range of cells, but as these are cell references not sure how to set it up.

Comment: What about `=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,N24,X24,AH24,AR24,BB24), ",0", "")`?

Comment: Here is one way: `=LET(α, HSTACK(N24,X24,AH24,AR24,BB24), ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(α,α<>0)))`

Comment: @Ike Will not work if the `N24` = `0`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Your second doesn't work if the first entry is zero.

Comment: The formula in your second comment above, if the first entry in the array is a zero, will not work because there is no comma preceding the zero if the zero is the first entry.

Comment: Yes I realized that when you commented sir, it will not work, I just tried to show OP, with the one provided by Ike madam,

Comment: Here is a way which can tackle the `0` if its in the beginning : `=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,TEXT(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5},N24,X24,AH24,AR24,BB24),"General;;"))` @RonRosenfeld Sir what you think of this one. Any advise?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I prefer the double Substitute function because you don't have to create (or hard-code) the array for the CHOOSE function. But, if the functions are available, the formula in your first comment would be my preference.

Comment: Ok, gotya understood.

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,T(N24),T(X24),T(AH24),T(AR24),T(BB24))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding @RonRosenfelds comment you can use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,N24,X24,AH24,AR24,BB24),"0, ",""),", 0","")
```

it will handle 0-values at any position.

Answer (score 0):

One could use `HSTACK()` and `FILTER()` function to remove the unwanted and then wrap within `TEXTJOIN()` or `ARRAYTOTEXT()`

[image]

---

```
=LET(α, HSTACK(N24,X24,AH24,AR24,BB24), ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(α,α<>0)))
```

---

Or,

```
=LET(α, HSTACK(N24,X24,AH24,AR24,BB24), TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(α,α<>0)))
```

---

[image]

---

Here is one more way for older versions:

[image]

---

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,TEXT(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5},N24,X24,AH24,AR24,BB24),"General;;"))
```

---

Comment: Both of these return #NAME?

Comment: @Charlotte that means those functions are not available in your versions of excel. what is your version of excel